# Unit test not working on VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I created a simple unit test project where I added simple test function to return string. However when I generated unit test project and try to run test method, Control never returns to me. I have to close VS as this never stops. Please see screenshot.

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Test()
    {
        return "testing";
    }
}
```

Added test method

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void TestTest()
    {
        Class1 target = new Class1(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        string expected = string.Empty; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        string actual;
        actual = target.Test();
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
    }
```

VS keeps running this test function and never returns a control.
[image]

**What could be the reason for this. Is it a bug in VS or conflict between versions of VS or something else.**

Please note: This test project is running on VS 2010. I have VS 2012 installed as well.

Comment: run in debug mode? step thru the test from the first line of the unit test? if it doesnt make it that far then pause the unit test runner and see where/what the call stacks are

Comment: What testagent are you using? Running through Visual Studio or through ReSharper? Are you seeing a messagebox pop up several times, for maybe a milisecond or two?

Comment: @wal: I tried in debug mode. But it's not even hitting breakpoint.

Comment: @Matthijs: I am not sure which TestAgent is used by default in VS2010. No messagebox popup at all.

Comment: @ShantanuGupta in your testmenu, is there a runsettingsfile (or similar, could be testsettings) configured? If there is, deselect it and run again.

Comment: @ShantanuGupta you tried in debug mode... even if it doesnt hit any breakpoint you will have the ability to pause (`||` icon) and then you can see the stack trace as per usual in the debug windows